# flash AS1 programm to AIR

Tags: flash

I have big AS1 project. I want to create AIR project to let it show on iPhone.

Is that possible without convertios AS1 to AS3?

Thanks,
Vladimir

Comment: How do you get a hold of reference material, compilers, and such for AS1?  Maybe some of the AS3 IDEs support AS1, but I haven't found a single tutorial on it.  I mostly just want to know what the language looks like, but haven't found a source.

Answer (score 1):

The project would have to be converted to use ActionScript 3. AIR for iOS was introduced with version 2.6 of AIR, which is AS3-only.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just load your AS1 swf in as3 app ? Air supports multiple swf even on ios